# Heap corruption alert when freing memory allocated to graph in C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, graph

MY code to destroy the graph below, when I call this function I get an alert saying heap corruption detected, picture attached. Can anyone know why it's happening?

```
void destroy_graph(Graph* self) {

    if (self != NULL) {
        if (self->edges != NULL) {
            for (int v = 0; v < self->V; v++) {
                EdgeNodePtr current = self->edges[v].head;
                while (current != NULL) {
                    EdgeNodePtr to_free = current;
                    current = current->next;
                    free(to_free);


                }
            }
            free(self->edges);
        }
        free(self);
    }
}
```

[Heap corruption deteced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJQ7O.png)

My code to create a graph

```
Graph new_graph(int vertices) {
    Graph self;

    self.V = vertices;
    self.edges = malloc(self.V * sizeof * self.edges);

        for (int v = 0; v < self.V; v++) {
            self.edges[v].head = NULL;
        }

    return self;
}
```

Here is the data structure:

```
typedef struct edge {
    int to_vertex;
    int weight;
} Edge;

typedef struct edgeNode {
    Edge edge;
    struct edgeNode *next;
} *EdgeNodePtr;

typedef struct edgeList {
    EdgeNodePtr head;
} EdgeList;

typedef struct graph {
    int V;
    EdgeList *edges;
} Graph;
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Graph`?

Comment: Are you sure you are heap allocating the `Graph` structure? Your `new_graph` just returns a `Graph` not a `Graph*`. We need to look at how these functions are being. If possible can you show a minimum reproducible example that has the error?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the type of edges exactly is, but in your `new_graph` function it should probably be:

```
self.edges = malloc(self.V * sizeof(self.edges[0]));
```

Comment: Here is the definition: typedef struct edge {
 int to_vertex;
 int weight;
} Edge;

typedef struct edgeNode {
 Edge edge;
 struct edgeNode *next;
} *EdgeNodePtr;

typedef struct edgeList {
 EdgeNodePtr head;
} EdgeList;

typedef struct graph {
 int V;
 EdgeList *edges;
} Graph;

Comment: `sizeof * self.edges` is exactly the same expression as `sizeof(self.edges[0])`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your `destroy_graph` function mostly looks right. But you have to be careful - you probably stack allocated the graph itself, which means you can't free it. EG the code

```c
Graph graph = new_graph(3);
destroy_graph(&graph);
```

would try to free a stack-allocated graph. That's the most likely error I can see.